# What is the BIOS key for Pegatron IPMSB-H61?

Tags: windows, bios, motherboard

Does anyone know the BIOS key I should press? I tried every key but anything doesn't seem to work.

My motherboard model: IPMSB-H61
Manufacturer: Pegatron

After browsing the web for a while, I found [this manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1023154/Pegatron-Ipmtb-Gs.html?page=23#manual) from [this post](https://www.techsupportforum.com/threads/pegatron-ipmsb-h61-bios-key.1248129/#post-7811205) but I'm not sure if this is the right manual since, the `Del` key didn't work either.

I'd really appreciate it if someone can point out to me the exact BIOS key so I can try it out and see if something's wrong with my system.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually at boot, pressing ESC will show the BIOS info which then tells you what the key is. Do note that Fast Startup may prevent you from getting there in the first place. If you can boot to windows, hold shift while pressing the restart button to boot directly to the recovery tools. There's often a button there to enter the BIOS too. If not, from windows reboot and then press escape repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

According to the
[manual page 23](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1023154/Pegatron-Ipmtb-Gs.html?page=23#manual):

> Just when the computer first starts up (before entering your operating system), press and hold the **`<Del>`** key to enter the BIOS setup program. (Press
> `<Ctrl+Alt+Delete>` to restart if you missed the opportunity.)

You should fast-press the key repeatedly on boot, since the
available time-period might be quite short.

Comment: Even shorter with Fast Boot enabled.